# How to receive user input from the console using javascript on repl.it online IDE

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am taking a javaScript coding challenge which require me to receive an input from the console. 
I am working with repl.it Online Ide as specified in the challenge and i can see a button for input right there on the compiler, i just don't know how to make the program receive inputs from the console.

I have tried using

```
    let input = readline();
```

and no results still. It keeps saying readline is not defined

Comment: Could you link the mentioned challenge or at least copy-paste it here?

Comment: Write a program which accepts a sequence of comma-separated numbers from console and
and generates a (n by m) of n​ ​times​ ​m​ ​=​ ​input_number​ matrix based on the number of input
given.
Suppose the following input is supplied to the program:
34,67,55,33,12,98 → 6 input.
Then, the output should be a 2​ ​by​ ​3​ ​matrix​ ​or​ ​a​ ​3​ ​by​ ​2​ ​matrix​ since both multiplication equals
to​ ​6​ ​the total number of the inputs:
Sample​ ​Output
[[34,​ ​67],​ ​[55,33],​ ​[12,98]]​ ​or​ ​[[34,67,55],[33,12,98]]

Comment: i would like to see your own way of solving it too. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are on node.js envairoment, you can use node.js readline api:
`https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html`

here is an repl example:
https://repl.it/KtCX